# c++ image array type

Tags: c++, image, casting

I'm working with fits images using C++. This format can hold 8/16/32 bits integers and 32/64 bits floating point arrays. The pixel size (variable type) is contained given by a header flag.
When I read one of this images using cfitsio library [http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/] I get a char array that holds all the pixels of the image:

```
char* array = new char[npix*bytepix]; // bytepix is the number of bytes per pixel
fits_read_img(infptr, datatype, first, npix, &nulval, lArray, &anynul, &status);
```

I can then get the "true" value of the pixel by a type cast. I.E. to get the value of the ith pixel for a 32 bits integer I would do:

```
int32_t pixelValue = ((int32_t*) lArray)[i];
```

I would like to know what is the most compact way of dealing with this in general, as I don't know what the pixel type will be when I write the code.

What I currently do is something like this:

```
switch(bytepix){
    case 1:{
      int8_t *vecVal = ((int8_t*) array );
    }
      break;
    case 2:{
      int16_t *vecVal = ((int16_t*) array );
    }
      break;
    case 4:{
      int32_t *vecVal = ((int32_t*) array );
    }
      break;
    case 8:{
      int64_t *vecVal = ((int64_t*) array );
    }
      break;
    default:
      cout << "error\n";
      break;
  }
}
```

That is clearly ugly and not very flexible.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called *generic programming*. It's a fundamental concept that splits the algorithm and the types it operates on. It is supported in C++ with *template functions* and *template classes*, and the whole C++ Standard Template Library is based upon it.

Basically, implement your processing function independently of the FITS pixel size:

```
template<typename Pixel>
void ProcessImage(Pixel *array, const int arr_length) {
  ...
}
```

And then call it with the respective pixel size:

```
...
case 1:
  ProcessImage<int8_t>(reinterpret_cast<int8_t *>(array), arr_length);
  break;
case 2:
  ProcessImage<int16_t>(reinterpret_cast<int16_t *>(array), arr_length);
  break;
...
```

A couple of thoughts:

1. You use C++ but write C-style code. I suggest you get familiar with C++ STL, containers and algorithms, they're exactly what is needed for image processing.
2. There is a C++ [CCfits](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software/fitsio/ccfits/) alternative to the cfitsio library that might suit you better.
3. There are libraries such as [Boost::GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) that implement a lot of image processing algorithms. They're heavily based on the templates and provide both complete functionality and good learning material.